# Should we do running and lifting on the same day or on different days?

Tags: running, weightlifting

While putting dishes from dish washer into the cabinets my arms got tired! So time to go back to gym and exercise! If I want to start for the first few weeks with moderate running in target heart zone of my age (32-M) for about 1 or 1.5 miles and also do some some sets of weight lifting that I can do 20lb to 25lb, Is that correct to do these two together in one day? or should I increase the running to 3 miles and one day only do that 3 mile running, the other day do just like half a mile running for a warm up and then just do more lifting?

Comment: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/9569/does-running-reduce-the-muscle-gained-by-gym-workouts/9575#9575 is very relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the level you're talking about, you can do all of it in one day. There's a related answer that discusses [how to breakup weight training and running once the two start to interfere with each other](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19490/what-are-some-good-strength-training-routines-for-runners/19501#19501). Primarily running and lifting tend to collide with lower body lifts.

Also, you may want to consider doing a real strength training program such as [Stronglifts 5x5](http://stronglifts.com/5x5/) or [Starting Strength](http://startingstrength.wikia.com/wiki/The_Starting_Strength_Novice/Beginner_Programs). Either will give you phenomenal results compared to just randomly lifting a dumbbell here and there.

Comment: Thanks for info. Is there a rule saying first do the running then the lifting or first lifting, then running?

Comment: @Blake If you're doing a real program like referenced above, you'll start missing your lifting numbers eventually and need more recovery time. I'd base it off of empirical results like that, and obviously your own time constraints.

Comment: Thanks for showing the programs, I am going to do 5x5 one...even has an app :)

Comment: @Blake Awesome, you'll love it. Good luck and feel free to ask any questions (and answer some!) on here as you go down that road.

Answer (score 1):

All of your proposed plans sound fine. The only reason to separate your lifting from cardio work would be if you gained access to heavier weights. If you were lifting close to bodyweight then splitting the running and lifting into separate workouts would help you focus on each one better. As is, combine or don't combine them according to your whim.

Comment: ". If you were lifting close to bodyweight then splitting the running and lifting into separate workouts would help you focus on each one better" ..  Great, now I also have some sort of criteria to know when I am actually doing some real lifting.