# Is cycling good or bad for lumbar hyperlordosis?

Tags: bicycling, posture, hamstring, spine

From Wikipedia about [Lumbar hyperlordosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lordosis#Lumbar_hyperlordosis):

> Commonly known as swayback, it is common in dancers. Imbalances in
>   muscle strength and length are also a cause, such as **weak hamstrings**,
>   or tight hip flexors (psoas). A major feature of lumbar hyperlordosis
>   is a forward pelvic tilt, resulting in the pelvis resting on top of
>   the thighs.

That means cycling, which uses the hamstrings a lot should have corrective effects for hyperlordosis. Is this reasoning correct, or are there other factors that need to be considered?

Comment: Anyone else notice that the guy in the picture is wearing cycling shorts?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say that cycling is "bad" for your health. There's solid [research that cycling can fix a bum knee](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3468609), as an example:

> It is suggested that cycling might be a useful exercise in the
>   rehabilitation of patients with injuries to the anterior cruciate
>   ligament, medial collateral ligament of the knee or achilles tendon.

And just to ground everyone else, the hip muscles in general form a network that is often treated as a group, and iliopsoas is a compound muscle created by the [psoas major](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2796950/) and the [iliacus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iliacus_muscle). The whole web of muscles in there often serve to provide different leverage points. At a certain angle one muscle is the prime mover and then past that angle a different muscle has better leverage, especially in [adduction vs abduction](https://www.machinedesign.com/medical/what-s-difference-between-abduction-and-adduction-biomechanics): stuff like that. [And for a terrific video on the architecture and function of the iliopsoas watch this video. It shows the interaction of anterior pelvic tilt really well.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Agc2mOW4p1U)

[image]

A humbling thing to realize is that the human body isn't fully understood, [and the psoas major is in that camp](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2796950/):

> The function of the psoas major is another area of controversy and
>   uncertainty in the literature. It is well established that the psoas
>   functions as a primary flexor of the hip joint [...] but it is the
>   other actions that are not well understood. There are several
>   hypotheses that have been put forward that are worthy of
>   consideration.

I don't know if there's any research linking tight hip flexors to cycling, and it's going to be dose-dependent if that research is done. [But anecdotally, tight hip flexors and lots of cycling seem to present together](https://www.ilovebicycling.com/hip-stretches-for-cyclists-relieve-tight-hip-flexors/).

I don't think it's worth tar-and-feathering cycling though, because [sitting at a desk is a great way to pick up anterior pelvic tilt](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/2638/7091) as well but of course you get none of the benefits that come from cycling.

I would look at cycling through a rather simple lens: it's a great activity and a great exercise, but it's not a whole body exercise and it has body position that's not anatomically "normal". It limits your range of motion and loads a lot more of you in some parts (legs) than others (arms). [22% of cyclists in a study reported overuse injuries in the lower back](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20847225).

Strength training (squats, deadlift, press) have been a staple in professional cycling for a long time. I remember reading [Greg LeMond's book](https://amzn.to/2DnOVoH) in the mid 90's with pictures of him in a squat rack. [I provided an answer to a guy asking about strength training for runners](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/19501/7091), and I would recommend the same for a cyclist in lieu of a more structured program.

Whether or not cycling is good for lumbar hyperlordosis (and it probably isn't), the way to fix it is the same tried and true rx: strengthen the whole chest-through-knee muscle chain with full range of motion strength training.